# How Many Harry Potter Chocolate Frogs Must I Buy?

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

Each Chocolate Frog comes with *one* collectable illustrated wizard card (very cool and not dorky at all, honest). There are equal odds of each card being in a pack (i.e., they have all been produced and distributed evenly). How many packs must we buy in order to have an 80% chance of having obtained all 12 cards? How about 90%? Thanks.

Comment: Why would someone vote this down?!

Comment: Maybe they're a muggle.

Comment: Aside from the Potter jokes, how many cards are in one deck?  You may want to edit your question and add that answer.

Comment: Thanks @jimmcnamara, I amended my question.

Answer (score 2):

[This website on the coupon collector's problem](http://www.randomservices.org/random/urn/Coupon.html) under item 11a (adapted to 12 items from 6) states that the chance you complete your set on purchase $n$ is $\sum_{j=0}^{11} (-1)^j{11 \choose j}\left( \frac {11-j}{12} \right)^{n-1}$ but gives no derivation.  You can add up starting with $n=12$ until you get to the desired success probability.

Comment: The expression comes from the inclusion-exclusion principle, and really gives the chance you have not completed your set by purchase $n$.  So find the $n$ that reduces it to $0.1$ or $0.2$ and you are there.  I would argue the lower limit should be $1$, but it doesn't matter much.